# how to convert java class String to xsd:string type?

Tags: java, android, xml, xsd, jaxb

The following code returns `java.lang.string` and I want it to be `xsd:string`, how can it be done?

```
Element e = getDocumentBuilder().newDocument().createElement("value");
e.setAttribute("type", v.getClass().toString());
```

in general, how can i convert any class to xsd:type ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by your question because xsd:string maps directly (from an XSD/xml file) to a java.lang.String. See:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnazq.html

Therefore, if you are in Java, then you would use java.lang.String everywhere you want an 'xsd:string'.

Comment: i'm in java trying to convert class to xml element using jaxb with XmlAdapter, and i want to add its dataType